# Parsing and grouping text in a string using Python

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I need to parse a series of short strings that are comprised of 3 parts: a question and 2 possible answers. The string will follow a consistent format:

This is the question "answer_option_1 is in quotes" "answer_option_2 is in quotes"

I need to identify the question part and the two possible answer choices that are in single or double quotes.

Ex.: 
What color is the sky today? "blue" or "grey"
Who will win the game 'Michigan' 'Ohio State'

How do I do this in python?

Comment: `Where's the problem? 'It's in the quotes.'`

Comment: That's not a consistent format. Are you sure you mean `"blue" or "grey"` not `"blue" "grey"`?

Comment: by consistent I mean a question and 2 possible answers in either single or double quotes. Some may have question marks, an or between the answers or even apostrophes to make it more messy.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Who will win the game 'Michigan' 'Ohio State'"
>>> re.match(r'(.+)\s+([\'"])(.+?)\2\s+([\'"])(.+?)\4', s).groups()
('Who will win the game', "'", 'Michigan', "'", 'Ohio State')
```

Answer (score 1):

If your format is a simple as you say (i.e. *not* as in your examples), you don't need regex. Just `split` the line:

```
>>> line = 'What color is the sky today? "blue" "grey"'.strip('"')
>>> questions, answers = line.split('"', 1)
>>> answer1, answer2 = answers.split('" "')
>>> questions
'What color is the sky today? '
>>> answer1
'blue'
>>> answer2
'grey'
```

Comment: Thanks.  It will be more like my examples than always clean syntax.  I need to allow for some variability in how the questions are constructed but not every permutation.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you can use regex.

```
import re
robj = re.compile(r'^(.*) [\"\'](.*)[\"\'].*[\"\'](.*)[\"\']')
str1 = "Who will win the game 'Michigan' 'Ohio State'"
r1 = robj.match(str1)
print r1.groups()
str2 = 'What color is the sky today? "blue" or "grey"'
r2 = robj.match(str2)
r2.groups()
```

Output:

```
('Who will win the game', 'Michigan', 'Ohio State')
('What color is the sky today?', 'blue', 'grey')
```

Comment: This will not parse correctly quotes inside quotes: `"Who will win the game \"'Michigan' or 'Ohio State\" \"spam\""`

Comment: Thanks pyfunc.  this seems to be working in multiple permutations of the question...

Answer (score 0):

Pyparsing will give you a solution that will adapt to some variability in the input text:

```
questions = """\
What color is the sky today? "blue" or "grey"
Who will win the game 'Michigan' 'Ohio State'""".splitlines()

from pyparsing import *

quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)
q_and_a = SkipTo(quotedString)("Q") + delimitedList(quotedString, Optional("or"))("A")

for qn in questions:
    print qn
    qa = q_and_a.parseString(qn)
    print "qa.Q", qa.Q
    print "qa.A", qa.A
    print
```

Will print:

```
What color is the sky today? "blue" or "grey"
qa.Q What color is the sky today? 
qa.A ['blue', 'grey']

Who will win the game 'Michigan' 'Ohio State'
qa.Q Who will win the game 
qa.A ['Michigan', 'Ohio State']
```